# Loop through nested array in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm having problem to populate the 'p' tags with text looping through the nested array in object.I'm trying to achieve to show the text from the array into the 'p' tags based on the 'title' condition. For example if the 'title == Home' then display the text content for the home page. And if it is 'title == Projects' then display the text in three different 'p' tags. Any help will be appreciated.

I've three html pages with 'p' tags with ids as under.

```
//home.html
<p id="t1"></p>

//about.html
<p id="t1"></p>

//projects.html
<p id="t1"></p>
<p id="t2"></p>
<p id="t3"></p>

// Object with nested array
myObj = {
    "pages": [
        { "title":"Home", "text":[ "some text"] },
        { "title":"About", "text":[ "some text" ] },
        { "title":"Project", "text":[ "some text 1", "some text 2", "some text 3"] }
    ]
}

// looping though array in object
for (let i = 0; i < myObj.pages.length; i++) {
        let pageTitle += myObj.pages[i];

          for (let j = 0;  j < myObj.pages[i]; j++) {                
            let pageText += myObj.pages[i][j].text;
         }   
}

// display the content for the specific page title
  if(pageTitle == "Home"){
        document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = dispaly text here
    }
 if(pageTitle == "About"){
        document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = dispaly text here
    }   
 if(pageTitle == "Project"){
        document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = dispaly text 1 here
        document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = dispaly text 2 here
        document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML = dispaly text 3 here
    }
```

Comment: You can't have multiple times the same id

Comment: @others i believe that those "duplicate id's" are separate pages, but he wants to use a single script for those pages.

Comment: @KarelG Then he won't be able to retrieve the elements from different pages

Comment: `let pageTitle += myObj.pages[i];` seems problematic as `myObj.pages[i]` is an object

Comment: Chip - if the object includes data for all three pages, how do you know which page you are currently on?

Comment: Are you getting any console error log?

Comment: @nnnnnn you can check the url ... but this question isn't so clear. What wants the OP to achieve? How is that object being provided (ajax, templating,...)? Are those id's always like that (t1, t2, ...tN)? ect

Comment: Can you change `myObj` at all? This would be trivial if you could index your `text` arrays rather than have them as a nested array.

Comment: You first need to initialize a variable before concatenating it. That is, do `let pageTitle = ""` and then `pageTitle += "whatever"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could just change the structure of your object (as suggested by @Richardson), there is a better way to do this.

```
myObj = {
    pages: {
        Home: {
            text: ["some text"] 
        },
        About: {
            text: ["some text"]
        },
        Project: {
            text: ["some text 1", "some text 2", "some text 3"]
        }
    }
}
//var pageTitle = document.title; // uncomment this
var pageTitle = "Project"; // comment this
var pageTextArray = myObj.pages[pageTitle].text;

pageTextArray.forEach(function(v, i){
    document.getElementById("t"+(i+1)).innerHTML = v;
});
```

Comment: @Richardson -> seems like it is working. Let me play around with it more. Thank you

Comment: -> seems like it is working. Let me experiment with it more. Thank you

Comment: Ok. Just don't forget to uncomment and comment the lines that I have showed in comments in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial with your current setup, and supersonically trivial if you can make a slight change to `myObj`.

---

Current setup:

```js
myObj = {
    "pages": [
        { "title":"Home", "text":[ "some text"] },
        { "title":"About", "text":[ "some text" ] },
        { "title":"Project", "text":[ "some text 1", "some text 2", "some text 3"] }
    ]
}

var pageTitle = "Home"; // or "About" or "Project"

var page = myObj.pages.find(function(p){ return p.title == pageTitle;})
console.log(page.text)

document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = page.text[0]
```

```html
<p id="t1"></p>
```

If you change `myObj` to an object literal with the page title as the key this becomes even easier.

```js
myObj = {
    "pages": {
        "Home": { "text":[ "some text"] },
        "About": { "text":[ "some text" ] },
        "Project":{ "text":[ "some text 1", "some text 2", "some text 3"] }
    }
}

var pageTitle = "Home"; // or "About" or "Project"

var page = myObj.pages[pageTitle];
console.log(page.text)

document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = page.text[0];
```

```html
<p id="t1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider change your JSON like this

```
{
   "pages": {
     "home": {
       "text": [
        "some text"
       ]
     },
     "aboutus": {
       "text": [
         "some text"
       ]
     },
    "project": {
      "text": [
        "some text"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

if you change above format you don't need to loop through JSON.

Comment: Why didnt *I* think of that, 5 minutes ago!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the check for the page title and setting the `innerHTML` in one go using a nested `forEach`.

Here is an example.

```js
const pageTitle = "Project";

const myObj = {
  "pages": [
    { "title":"Home", "text":[ "some text"] },
    { "title":"About", "text":[ "some text" ] },
    { "title":"Project", "text":[ "some text 1", "some text 2", "some text 3"] }
  ]
}

myObj.pages.forEach( item => {
  if (item.title === pageTitle) {
    item.text.forEach( (text, idx) => {
      document.getElementById("t"+(idx+1).toString()).innerHTML = text
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<!--home.html-->
<p id="t1"></p>

<!--about.html-->
<p id="t1"></p>

<!--projects.html-->
<p id="t1"></p>
<p id="t2"></p>
<p id="t3"></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: make answer less awful. Sorry about that.

You could try filling up a display array from the loop and then use this for the innerHTML call.

Something like:

```
const pageTitle = 'Home';
let displayArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myObj.pages.length; i++) {
        if(myObj.page[i].title === pageTitle) {

          for (let j = 0;  j < myObj.pages[i].text.length; j++) {                
            displayArray.push(myObj.pages[i].text[j]);
         }   
}
document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = displayArray.join();
```

OLD ANSWER
You need to create a reference to your object something like `document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = myObj.pages[0].text[0]`. However this isn't very dynamic and probably no better than just writing out the html by hand. What you need to look into is looping. Try this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) as a starter.

Comment: Yes I need to loop through it and display the content dynamically. Is my for loop correct ?